# Extending DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, extend, web-controls

I would like to extend the ASP.NET DataGrid web control to add lots of additional features but most important of all, I would like to make the body of the grid scrollable.

I have the HTML worked out but overriding the rendering of the control is confusing. The basic structure of final control should look like so:

```
<div id="grid1" class="grid">
<div class="grid-header">
    <div class="grid-header-l"></div>
    <div class="grid-header-c">
        <div class="grid-header-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper">Grid Header</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-header-r"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-body">
    <div class="grid-column-headers">
        <div class="grid-column-headers-l"></div>
        <div class="grid-column-headers-c">
            <div class="grid-column-headers-wrapper">
                <table class="grid-column-header-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="grid-column-header-cell asc">
                                    <div class="grid-column-header-cell-wrapper">
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-text" title="Column Header Name">Column Header Name</div>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="grid-column-header-button" title="Hide/Show Columns"><span></span></a>
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-divider"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="grid-column-header-cell">
                                    <div class="grid-column-header-cell-wrapper">
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-text" title="Column Header Name">Column Header Name</div>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="grid-column-header-button" title="Hide/Show Columns"><span></span></a>
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-divider"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="last">
                                <div class="grid-column-header-cell">
                                    <div class="grid-column-header-cell-wrapper">
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-text" title="Column Header Name">Column Header Name</div>
                                        <a href="javascript:;" class="grid-column-header-button" title="Hide/Show Columns"><span></span></a>
                                        <div class="grid-column-header-divider"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-column-headers-r"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-body-content">
        <div class="grid-body-content-t">
            <div class="grid-body-content-t-l"></div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-t-c"></div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-t-r"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-body-content-m">
            <div class="grid-body-content-m-l"></div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-m-c">
                <div class="grid-body-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="scroll-wrapper">
                        <table class="grid-content-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="grid-content-cell">Cell Text/Value</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-m-r"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-body-content-b">
            <div class="grid-body-content-b-l"></div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-b-c"></div>
            <div class="grid-body-content-b-r"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know what the best approach should be? Can anyone point me to some tutorial? I have noticed one where the author captured the rendered html before it is sent to the response stream and altered it. I do not like to use that approach however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I only wanted to modify the output of the control, 'extending' the control actually meant that I only had to override the rendering.

I found articles on control adapters that one can use to alter the output. A project exists on [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) named '[CSS Control Adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/)'. It has been very helpful on more controls than just the  DataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ScrollingGridView.aspx) approach. Works good for me.